# Can you use a single vector image as an adaptive icon for Android with Cordova?

Tags: android, cordova

I have an Android app built with Cordova natively which previously used PNG images for icons which we are attempting to convert to an adaptive icon.  Full disclosure - I rarely if ever use Android Studio but can and will as needed.  The docs for Cordova (https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/images.html#android) show referencing multiple image files for adaptive icons:

```
<platform name="android">
  <icon background="res/icon/android/ldpi-background.xml" density="ldpi" foreground="res/icon/android/ldpi-foreground.xml" src="res/android/ldpi.png" />
  <icon background="res/icon/android/mdpi-background.xml" density="mdpi" foreground="res/icon/android/mdpi-foreground.xml" src="res/android/mdpi.png" />
  <icon background="res/icon/android/hdpi-background.xml" density="hdpi" foreground="res/icon/android/hdpi-foreground.xml" src="res/android/hdpi.png" />
  <icon background="res/icon/android/xhdpi-background.xml" density="xhdpi" foreground="res/icon/android/xhdpi-foreground.xml" src="res/android/xhdpi.png" />
  <icon background="res/icon/android/xxhdpi-background.xml" density="xxhdpi" foreground="res/icon/android/xxhdpi-foreground.xml" src="res/android/xxhdpi.png" />
  <icon background="res/icon/android/xxxhdpi-background.xml" density="xxxhdpi" foreground="res/icon/android/xxxhdpi-foreground.xml" src="res/android/xxxhdpi.png" />
</platform>
```

I know Android wants a "vector drawable" image which is similar to an SVG and I can convert an SVG to that format.  However, the docs for Android (https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_adaptive) seem to call for a single vector image at 108dp x 108dp.  I am not exactly sure what "dp" means but I assume it is a relative coordinate system for the vector.

What confuses me is that Android docs call for a single vector at 108dp x 108dp but the Cordova docs show linking 6 individual XML files (vector drawable images).  Why would you need 6 different vector images?  Doesn't that defeat the purpose?  Can someone who has made this work clarify what is expected of these 6 different image files in Cordova for Andoid?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've got this working, but the Cordova documentation was a bit unclear, and the "cordova prepare" step seems a bit buggy.

You only need one vector drawable foreground icon, which (as you say) can be generated from an SVG. This should be 108 x 108 units and should have an 18 unit safe area border. For the background I used a solid colour, but you should be able to use a single vector drawable too.

The reason for repeating it in every line seems to be that the fallback PNG *does* need to be different for each one (as it always has).

There are a few things to watch out for (at least at the time of writing).

1. If you *are* using a solid colour background you **must** call your colour resources file anything *except* colors.xml (contrary to what the [cordova docs](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/11.x/config_ref/images.html#adaptive-icon-with-colors) say). Otherwise it will clober the native android colors.xml that gets autogenerated, and cordova will give you a cryptic message about "text cannot be null". For example, mine is specified like this:

   ```
   <resource-file src="res/values/droidcolors.xml" target="/app/src/main/res/values/droidcolors.xml" />
   ```

   The contents of the file should follow the cordova docs though, viz

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <resources>
     <color name="background">#51c5d6</color>
   </resources>
   ```

   NB if (like me) you initially call this file colors.xml you will have to remove and re-add the android platform once you rename it.
2. Also contrary to (or at least, not mentioned in) the cordova documentation, if you are using a vector drawable foreground icon then you **must** also specify a monochrome vector icon or your foreground icon will not get used (and the app will fall back to using your PNG src attribute).

   This looks like a bug in the logic used by cordova-android/lib/prepare.js to me, especially since no error or warning gets emitted, but at least the workaround is easy. And perhaps I just misunderstood things.

   Anyway, this is the config that worked for me:

   ```
   <icon background="@color/background" density="ldpi" foreground="res/icon/android/drawable/ic_launcher.xml" monochrome="res/icon/android/drawable/ic_launcher-monochrome.xml" src="res/icon/android/mipmap-ldpi/ic_launcher.png" />
   <icon background="@color/background" density="mdpi" foreground="res/icon/android/drawable/ic_launcher.xml" monochrome="res/icon/android/drawable/ic_launcher-monochrome.xml" src="res/icon/android/mipmap-mdpi/ic_launcher.png"/>
   <icon background="@color/background" density="hdpi" foreground="res/icon/android/drawable/ic_launcher.xml" monochrome="res/icon/android/drawable/ic_launcher-monochrome.xml" src="res/icon/android/mipmap-hdpi/ic_launcher.png"/>
   <icon background="@color/background" density="xhdpi" foreground="res/icon/android/drawable/ic_launcher.xml" monochrome="res/icon/android/drawable/ic_launcher-monochrome.xml" src="res/icon/android/mipmap-xhdpi/ic_launcher.png"/>
   <icon background="@color/background" density="xxhdpi" foreground="res/icon/android/drawable/ic_launcher.xml" monochrome="res/icon/android/drawable/ic_launcher-monochrome.xml" src="res/icon/android/mipmap-xxhdpi/ic_launcher.png"/>
   <icon background="@color/background" density="xxxhdpi" foreground="res/icon/android/drawable/ic_launcher.xml" monochrome="res/icon/android/drawable/ic_launcher-monochrome.xml" src="res/icon/android/mipmap-xxxhdpi/ic_launcher.png"/>
   ```

(Whilst working on this I discovered that some helpful devs have packaged the vd-tool that android studio uses to convert svgs to the android drawable format as a CLI binary. Various builds exist but the one by [Alex Lockwood](https://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2018/11/android-studio-svg-to-vector-cli.html) worked for me. It saves a lot of time not having to open Studio just to convert an svg.)

Comment: Brilliant answer. Ridiculous that the Cordova docs dont mention the monochrome icon! This was my problem for a long time and I never realised that monochrome was REQUIRED. Thank you so much